# OpenGL multipass shadow maps on Qt are not rendered

Tags: c++, qt, opengl, glsl

I'm trying to render dynamic shadows casted from the point light on some cubes. However, like there are no shadows at all on the cubes, particularly on the silver cube:

[image]

In my program I use Qt OpenGL API together with the native OpenGL one. I do two passes: 1. create a depth texture (glGenTextures()), create a framebuffer (glGenFramebuffers()) and attach the texture to that (glFramebufferTexture()). Then render all cubes to that framebuffer. 2. Render as usually all scene to the screen with using that texture in the shaders. I use QOpenGLShaderProgram class for creating shader programs.

How I calculate the shadows in the fragment shader:

```
float isFragInShadow(vec3 fragPos)
{
    vec3 relFragPos = fragPos - lightPos;
    float closestDepth = texture(depth_map, relFragPos).r;
    closestDepth *= far_plane;

    float currentDepth = length(relFragPos);

    float bias = max(0.05 * (1.0 - dot(normalize(-relFragPos), Normal)), 0.005);
    float shadow = currentDepth - bias > closestDepth ? 1.0 : 0.0;

    return shadow;
}

...

float isShadow = isFragInShadow(FragPos);
vec3 resColor = ambient * obj_material.ambient + (1.0 - isShadow) * (diffuse * obj_material.diffuse + specular * obj_material.specular);
```

I also tried to render to the screen the depth texture and the result is following:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/qM9a1.png

How I render:

```
vec3 lightToFrag = FragPos - lightPos;
float closestDepth = texture(depth_map, lightToFrag).r;

Color = vec4(vec3(closestDepth), 1.0);
```

Why can I not see shadows in the scene?

Comment: What transformation matrices are you using when drawing to the shadowmap?

Comment: @Frank in the geometry shader I use array of projection * view matrices in each direction (+X, +Y, +Z, -X, -Y, -Z), so transforming each vertex to the corresponding light space coordinates. In the vertex shader I use model matrix.